Should I caulk gaps where the top concrete platform meets my concrete steps?
Do I need to seal the gaps where the top concrete platform on my front porch meets the concrete steps (circled blue in picture below)?
I see people online say to seal the gaps between the lower concrete slab / sidewalk and their steps (circled red in picture below), but I can't seem to find any information on the top concrete slab. Should I seal it, or is it for drainage or something? I have some Sikaflex Concrete Fix leftover from a previous project and looking to use it up.


Do you get freezing temperatures?  If so sealing might be wanted/needed to prevent cracks.

Yes, I do get freezing temps by me. Thanks for the response

Not only freezing temps; if you have sufficient water flowing through, it can cause undermining of the soil.
